# An object instantiated outside of a function. How can I access from the fuction?

Tags: python

Tried to access as argument of the function. Not working!

```
object = class()

def foo(object):
    object.method

foo()
```

Not working!

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.

Comment: explain the reason of down voting!

Comment: you have to provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example.

Comment: And "can't remember the error message" is not an excuse for not providing the complete error message including traceback.

Comment: Saying things like "I can't remember the error message" shows you don't really care very much about this question.  And if you don't care, why should we?

Comment: Your question doesn't even have *the basics* of what is required. You need to provide example input/desired output, and code that accurately reflects what you are doing. If you are getting an error-message, then *provide the error message including the full stack trace*. Further more, your problem description "Not working!" is not an adequate problem specification. Please see [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: For-what-its-worth, you can't name a `class` "class"—doing so produces a syntax error because it's a [reserved word](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) in Python, which cannot be used as ordinary identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to be referring to `object` as `obj` since you should not be overriding built-in classes, especially since its a new-style class.

Simply put, `obj` within the function definition is a parameter name, not the variable `obj` you have assigned.

Therefore, when calling the function `foo`, you need to provide it the parameter it asks for. So your code should be like this:

```
foo(obj)
```

not `foo()`